# Concatenate error after repeating array

Tags: python, numpy, concatenation, repeat

I have 5 arrays I want to repeat 600 times and then make into one big array

```
lenE=600
E=array([49.73199462, 49.73799861, 49.74400261, 49.74894938, 49.7500066 ....])
Lat3E=[E]*lenE
```

I do this for all my arrays A, B, C, D and E. E is shorter then the other arrays. When I try to combine then the error is:

```
lat=np.concatenate((Lat3A,Lat3B,Lat3C,Lat3D,Lat3E))
ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly.
```

This is because Lat3E is a combination of 600 arrays. It looks like this:

```
[array([49.73199462, 49.73799861,....)],array([49.73199462, 49.73799861,....]),array([49.73199462, 49.73799861,...)],...]
```

How do I make this long 600 array into 1 long array to make the error go away?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unclear what you're asking, consider providing [mcve].

Comment: Are `Lat3B`, `Lat3C`, etc. also lists of arrays, or just regular one-dimensional arrays?

Comment: They are all the same, so lists of arrays

Comment: I don't think that it's a good idea to have lists of numpy arrays. Consider using 2D arrays. This `Lat3E=[E]*lenE`, for example, could be rewritten as `Lat3E = np.tile(E, (lenE, 1))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can concatenate multiple lists of arrays like this:

```
lat = np.concatenate(Lat3A + Lat3B + Lat3C + Lat3D + Lat3E)
```

[`np.concatenate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) takes a sequence as input, so a list or a tuple will do. If you have multiple lists, you need to convert them to a single list, for example with `+` (or you could also do `[*Lat3A, *Lat3B, *Lat3C, *Lat3D, *Lat3E]`, or use [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain), ...) and then pass it to the function.

If all the original arrays are the same sizeAnother way of solving the same problem with NumPy only could be this:

```
lens = np.array([lenA, lenB, lenC, lenD, lenE])
lat = np.tile(lens[:, np.newaxis], (1, 600, 1)).reshape((-1,))
```

Comment: So what exactly does it do? Because I need the order to stay the same.

Comment: @Elise The order remains the same, it just concatenates all the lists into one.

Comment: @Elise I've added another possible NumPy solution, although only if all original arrays have the same size.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `Lat3E=[E]*lenE` you can use `np.repeat(E, lenE)` function.